# Почему выдает ошибку в выводе массива? ( Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15 at Main.main(Main.java:21) )

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] a = new int[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = random.nextInt(30);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

        int []b = new int[30];

        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
            if(i>15) {
                b[i]=2*a[i];
            }
            else {
                b[i]=a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае индекс превышает размер массива, к которому вы обращаетесь посредством этого индекса. Вы создали два массива `а` и `b` разной длины (15 и 30). И когда вы в:

```
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
    if(i>15) {
        b[i]=2*a[i];
    }
```

проходитесь по `i`, то для i>=15 a[i] не существует, так как длина `a` = 15 и компилятор выкидывает java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.